# React Data Grid Custom Row Renderer function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

I would like to convert the following `RowRender()` function to Typescript

```
const RowRenderer = ({ renderBaseRow, ...props }) => {
  const color = props.idx % 2 ? "green" : "blue";
  return <div style={{ color }}>{renderBaseRow(props)}</div>;
};
```

complete sample here:
[React Data Grid - Intercepting a row](https://codesandbox.io/s/5zr5r03y44?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js)

My naive approach is

```
interface RowRender {
  idx: Number
};

const rowRenderer = ({ renderBaseRow, ...props }: {renderBaseRow: Function, props: RowRender}) => {
  const color = props.idx % 2 ? "green" : "blue";
  return <div style={{ color }}>{renderBaseRow(props)}</div>;
};
```

but vscode still not happy with props.idx

> Property 'idx' does not exist on type '{ props: RowRender; }'.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide the typings for the `RowRenderer` component by declaring it as a functional component, with the required generic parameter. You may also refer to the [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-data-grid/index.d.ts#L105) over here.

```
interface IRowRender {
  renderBaseRow: (e: any) => void
  idx: number;
}

const rowRenderer: React.FC<IRowRender> = ({ renderBaseRow, ...props }) => {
  const color = props.idx % 2 ? "green" : "blue";
  return <div style={{ color }}>{renderBaseRow(props)}</div>;
};
```

Comment: thanks working :) but had to replace "renderBaseRow: (e: any) => void" with "renderBaseRow: (e: any) => ReactNode"

Comment: Ahh Yeah, makes sense, becase it returns a ReactNode. Anyways, I am not very familiar with this library, thats why I used `any` for `renderBaseRow`. You might want to look for the right typings for it!